# How to align GIF in Readme.md file?

Tags: html, github, alignment, markdown, readme

I am facing some problems with aligning GIF's in the github markdown file or README.md.

I used to align gif's similar to how we align images using the `<img>` tag.

Example *(previously)*

```
<img align=right width=150 src="file_name.gif" /> <--FOR GIF's-->
<img align=right width=150 src="file_name.png" /> <--FOR Images-->
```

But now I am unable to align the gif's as mentioned above.

The following code works with the GIF alignment to the right. *(Now)*

```
<p align=right>
<img width=150 src="file_name.gif" />
</p>
```

Since my aim is to align the GIF right next to the paragraph similar to this, here it deals with an img but **I want it to be for a GIF**

[image: right alignment of image]

How can I align the GIF properly in the README.md file?

Comment: Pls keep appropriate [Title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648) for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution. Go to the link below and do the required changes as mentioned below.

[Github Accessibility](https://github.com/settings/accessibility)

You can follow the image below -

- By default for you it might be `Sync with System`, **you should change it to** `enabled`. Further you can confirm the changes i.e., `right alignment` of the GIF's in my case.

[image: Github new feature]